# On the Euler line

Tags: reference-request, euclidean-geometry

Do you know of some books or papers dealing with the history of the Euler line?

Was L. Euler the first mathematician that *notice* its existence? Are there any interesting paragraphs out there discussing the fact that apparently it was not widely known in Ancient Greece?

Thanks in advance for your replies.

Comment: Here https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Orthocenter.html it says the orthocenter was named in 1865.  So what did Euler actually say in 1765?

Comment: a) All that Weisstein is saying there is that the orthocenter was christened thus in 1865... b) Mathworld is not a reliable source.

Comment: Lots of things known now were not known in Ancient Greece,  and what was not known is too vast to discuss. Guinand reviews some early history in [Euler Lines, Tritangent Centers, and Their Triangles](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2322671).

Comment: Mathworld is not always the most informative source, but for what is says, it is informative.

Comment: @Gerald Edgar: The wikipedia article is quite ingormative. Apparently Euler showed that several rriangle centres were collinear and this line is now called the Euler line.

Comment: @Conifold:  I am mainly interested in paragraphs about stuff they did not notice regarding collinearity or concurrence... Best regards!

Comment: (@MoziburUllah, I am frivolously amused by your typo "ingormative"! :)